# Can't use std::filesystem in code built with make and g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gnu

I have some problems with building my c++ app with make.
I have such c++ code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    auto iter = fs::directory_iterator(fs::current_path());
    while(iter._At_end())
    {
        cout << iter->path() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile object file with command:
`g++-9 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pthread -lstdc++fs -c -o main.o main.cpp`
But I have this error:

```
main.cpp:12:16: error: ‘class std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator’ has no member named ‘_At_end’
   12 |     while(iter._At_end())
      |                ^~~~~~~
```

So, I cant use members of classes of std::filesystem namespace but if I wanna use only class(for example std::filesystem::path), so everything is ok.

Versions of soft:

```
g++-9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
GNU Make 4.2.1
```

Hope you'll help me.

Comment: `_At_end` is not a part of the standard library. Why do you think you can use it?

Comment: Install the `g++-10` package and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: Well, I saw it woked on MSVC compiler. Does it means that g++ does not support this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `_At_end()` and everything will be ok.